# I got error when i try to acces an image folder?

Tags: c#

Iam tried to access an image folder,but when i try to run i got an error

> "C:/Users/glos/Desktop/My Proj /My Proj/projects//images1' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected."

My code

```
public object post([FromBody]string value)
    {



        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("C:\\Users\\glos\\Desktop\\My Proj\\ projects\\images1");
        var images = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(image);
        }
        return (images);
    }
```

So how can i create a *virtual path*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know that the file exists in `C:\\Users\\glos\\Desktop` why do you need `Server.MapPath`? - it is needed only when you have a relative path like `~/folder1/folder2`.

You can also use [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Users\\glos\\Desktop\\My Proj...");
```